# Event onSort on Pagination plugin for EnhancedGrid

Tags: dojo, grid, pagination

I'm using Dojo 1.6.1. I have an EnhancedGrid with Pagination plugin and a QueryReadStore, that shows a list of users on my system retrieved from the server; The number of users can grow up to thousands. To make it easier for the administrators, we have a menu bar with the initials of the user's names, so when the administrator clicks on a letter, the grid shows the page where that letter starts. This works fine. The issue we have is that every time the administrator sorts the list by some field, we need to rebuild (or hide) the menu bar(to adapt it to the sorting selected). So what I would like is to have a event on the Pagination plugin to which I can connect, and get the sorting field selected by the administrator, and if it has changed, rebuild the menu bar. Any ideas on how to do that?

TIA

JL